# Cyanogen dialer not working after flashing C-apps bundle

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes, phone-app, force-close

Recently I installed CyanogenMod on my phone. I also decided to flash Cyanogen's new C-apps bundle.

After I did that, the new Cyanogen dialer keeps crashing whenever I try to make or receive calls. Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: If I were you, I'd be contacting the development team first, if possible. Have you tried that, friend?

Comment: @NVZ I'll try right now

Comment: Is this a Cyanogenmod 13 build? Capps only work in 12.1

Comment: @xangua Oh, well, there my problem. Yeah, this is cm13. Do you know how to revert it?

Comment: Basically flash the ROM again. The capps installer deletes and replace the dialer and other apps.

Comment: @xangua Can I just uninstall the dialer and other corrupt apps, than reflash gapps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki mentions that in order to use capps you need Cyanogenmod 12.1, what doesn't mention is that is not compatible with Cyanogenmod 13.

The wiki also comes with uninstall instructions. (You don't need to wipe and flash add I thought first).

**Uninstall**

Note: Requires Root

You will need to enter the following commands to remove C-Apps.

Connect your device to your computer and open a terminal or command prompt.

1. adb root
2. adb remount
3. adb shell rm /system/addon.d/01-cyngn.sh
4. Reflash CyanogenMod zip for your device

https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Cyanogen_Apps